# js syntax for excluding strings

Tags: javascript

Can I get a more efficient and syntax  correct version of this in JS please?

```
if (choice != "rock" or "paper" or "scissors") {
  return "invalid selection";
}
```

SO, if variable 'choice' is not equal to rock, or paper or scissors.

thanks!

Comment: Before you think of efficiency, please make sure it is working code.

Comment: sort of why I'm here... thanks anyway

Comment: `or` is not part of javascript syntax. Try `||` for `or` and `&&` for `and`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (choice != "rock" && choice != "paper" && choice != "scissors") {
  return "invalid selection";
}
```